# Simple DC-AC Inverter Circuit not working

Tags: oscillator, inverter, dc-ac

I am just an electronics enthusiast and I want to convert DC to AC. After searching I found this schematic from http://www.electronicshub.org/12v-dc-220v-ac-converter-circuit/ and tried to implement it.
[image: **enter image description here**]
I have no output on the transformer. Here are some things I have tried:

1. Replacing all components.
2. Checking the output of the astable multivibrator (12V about 54.5Hz Square wave with minimal overshoot on the rising edge.)

I am using a 12-0-12 CT 1A transformer. My project only requires less than 100 watts. Thank you.

Comment: That's boarderline a schematic. Use the built in tool to create a normal schematic. Have you simulated it?

Comment: I tried with multisim but it always gave an error. I am not sure why.

Comment: Then you need to find out why. Anything beyond a simple battery and lightbulb will require a simulation at some point and this circuit will definily require a deeper understanding.

Comment: We use schematics here, not that cartoon that was the first thing I saw.  -1 and not even bothering to read the text.  Come back where you're ready to talk about electronics like a grown-up.

Comment: Use LTspice and learn how to use it

Answer (score 1):

If you've built it the way it is shown in your diagram it can't work.

What you need to do is connect the MOSFET gate, the BJT collector, the 680R and the 2u2 capacitor on each side.

[image]